# Whats the difference between Surface and Card in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-card, android-jetpack-compose-surface

It's basically the same right? They have the same properties. I really don't know when I have to use each.

Technically Cards is for a Card view but Surface have the same properties like `elevation` and `border`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at Card composable source you will understand that card is a surface with default elevation and, the background shape is MaterialTheme.shapes.medium

as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Card(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.Indication,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0)) "Cards are Surfaces that display content and actions on a single topic."

Answer (score 5):

It's all about **Material Design Guidelines**

When you read the Material Design [documentation](https://material.io/), you will understand that these two components are used for different purposes.

`Surface` is used when you want a surface for your `UI`, you can set the `background` color, shape etc.

`Card` on the other hand, have default elevation(Material Design Standard) and pretty much have every property as the `surface`.

It's All about following **Material Design Guidelines**